# Should I keep working for company that didn't pay workers for a month?

Tags: resignation

So I work at a startup which is in its product building phase. 2 months ago the ceo of the company asked us to work for one month free because the company was not generating any revenue. We agreed hoping we would get paid afterwards. After a couple of weeks, the ceo said that we would get equity instead of salary so most of my colleagues (which were my seniors) left.

When I was about to leave, the ceo said he would pay me, so I stayed as my salary was relatively less then my colleagues. After that one month passed (the free month - Month of May) then another month passed (June). Then on 10th of July I was supposed to be paid for the month of June but the ceo kept giving excuses as the payment is not passing through to everyone due to some new regulations and then he kept giving excuses and afterwards he said to do the payment through upwork. We then waited for 1 week after sending him our profiles then today he paid me on upwork for the month of July.

He didn't pay me for June. I decided to let it go as I wasn't given any task for 1 month but I think that is not my fault and this is a company so I think I should get paid for each month. Now today he sent a message to everyone saying we have closed a big client which is a public company (He has shown me the contract) and he is saying that we are going to work hard coming months, but the issue is I'm a frontend developer and there is no one else on the product team other than me - no backend devs and no designers, so the product development is actually on full stop. There are only data entry people.

I'm really worried that I would work again for one month and I won't get paid for it and this last month/ This has been really frustrating and annoying waiting for the salary.

Should I resign?

Comment: Isn't this the exact same case as another post a few hours ago by a similar user ID? Like, I think the title was, "How to make American employer pay for work done in India". (I'm not finding it right now -- was former one deleted by mods?)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree

Comment: Tried to clarify title.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't have job per se but I have a consultant contract going on which pays way more than my current salary but it is a contract and I'm not sure how long it will last

Comment: "the company asked us to work for one month free because the company was not generating any revenue. We agreed"  You should never agree to work for free, especially when you know that the company is not making money.

Comment: @sf02 I agree, I learnt my lesson I should've been more practical.

Comment: Equity in a company that isn't earning any money isn't worth anything.  So you're not getting any pay that way either.

Comment: Stop working for free.  Working for free is called slavery in the free world.  You being the only developer is a problem for the CEO to solve by **paying their employees**. At this point you should be asking for all pay owned to you and equity into the company.  You should get both without any promises to stay allowing you to immediately leave.  Of course the idea is you won’t leave, unless they stop paying you again, and I would offer no concessions on your future pay.

Comment: Is there any reason you shouldn't resign? Is this (your CEO asking you to work for free) even legal in your jurisdiction?

Answer (score 5):

I don't really like to give absolute advice, but my read is that you're being taken on a bit of a ride.

I would start looking for another job. In the meantime I would be spending free time at work building your skills. I would try to remain employed, just so there isn't a resume gap, if that is possible, but I would certainly not be working for free.

In addition, I would start giving ultimatums on when payments go through, and just leave if they are not met.

Ultimately your boss wants you treading water, paying you as little as he can get away with, until he gets a customer.

I wouldn't trust any sort of contract that you see. It's no doubt there are templates that are made up that can be filled in pretty easily.

Regarding the business prospects, if things were looking good, your CEO would be able to secure outside investment to bridge the funding gap. They have not been able to. Your ability to analyse contracts is much less than outside investors who do this for a living.

If you are being employed, but there is no work to do, even if you are doing nothing all day, there is an opportunity cost. You could be earning money working for someone else.

And by the way, there are absolutely situations where it may be worthwhile to work for free for a period of time. It's not uncommon with some start-ups. But you have to have trust that everyone is being honest about prospects, and you have workers that understand the opportunity. Giving all the seniors walked out, it doesn't seem like the business is that viable.

Comment: “But you have to have trust” — exactly!  A start-up may well have cashflow troubles, and be temporarily unable to pay some wages.  But if its management is honest and open, it should admit the situation, give clear warning, and then make good on the back-pay once it's able.  (And if the management _does_ have that sort of integrity, the company's fortunes may well improve significantly thereafter, and hanging in there could be worthwhile.)  However, if management is _not_ open and honest about the situation, that's a big red flag!

Answer (score 3):

To put it  succinctly:

Employment is  an agreement in which two parties  benefit: The  employer benefits from having work done, which allows  them to make money.  The employee benefits from getting paid, which allows them to make money.  In the end, the only purpose of an employment contract is for both parties involved to make money.

Now, you are doing your  best to have the company make money, which is to say you are properly doing your work, which is  the part that is expected (not required, that's a different discussion and the two are separate concepts; what is "required" is not relevant here.  In this  case "expected" is a stronger statement than "required") of you.  Your company is not  doing what is  expected of them,  and are not even doing what is   required of them by the terms of your  contract, which is to pay your salary.

In short: This employment contract benefits only one party of it, and that party is not you.  Find  another employment contract which benefits you.